# Bulk upload and Java servlets

Tags: java, servlets, file-upload

What is the best way to upload a CSV file through a Java servlet on machine A that gets generated on Machine B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Compress the file. Compression typically reduces by 90% the size of CSV files.
2. If allowed, use ftp or sftp. There are many apache libraries to do that.
3. If ftp not allowed due to security concerns, you might want to use any of the Apache libraries httpclient and httpcore to "POST" the file to your server in B.

Comment: Is POST used for large files?

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately, there is no standard limit for HTML 4, AFAIK. In any case, POST allows you to send more data than GET.

Comment: in case of GET method we can have only 256 charectors send over the url but in case of POST it has no limit

Answer (score 0):

If you mean CSV generated on machine B, servlet running on machine A:

1. process on machine B generates
   CSV file (or detects it has been
   generated) then does a http post to
   push the CSV to the servlet.  This
   can be done in java or any system
   you like since you're servlet is
   just expecting HTTP.  Here is a 
   [Java example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386832/upload-a-file-using-http-put-in-java).
   or,
2. you could mount a common folder
   so that machine A and machine B can
   see the file, and the servlet could
   periodically check for the file. 
   Since you've said "upload" you
   probably mean option 1.

Comment: Can Perl scripts execute HTTP POSTs?

Comment: Yes (http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-5.836/lib/Net/HTTP.pm), If Perl is a part of your requirements you should state that in your initial post.