# java httpurlconnection http put error 400

Tags: java, http, httpurlconnection, put

I took the HTTP PUT code pretty much verbatim from [this example from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386832/upload-a-file-using-http-put-in-java) -- I am attempting to place an XML file into an ExistDB rest interface but I receive "*400 Bad Request*" values from the URLConnection getResponseCode() and see nothing at all recorded by the remote server, it is as if the request was never sent.

```
URL target = new URL( "http://domain.com:8080/exist/rest/db/collection/doc.xml" )
HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection) target.openConnection();
uc.setDoOutput(true);
uc.setDoInput(true);
uc.setRequestMethod("PUT");

uc.setConnectTimeout(CONNECT_TIMEOUT); // timeouts are both 2000L
uc.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT); //ms
uc.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "text/xml");

// basic Auth s.getLogin() already recorded as username:pwd format
String auth = new String( Base64.encodeBase64String( s.getLogin().getBytes() ));
auth = auth.replaceAll("\n",""); // sun bug_id 6459815
uc.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + auth ); 

uc.connect(); // tried moving this to after the body section below

PrintWriter body = new PrintWriter(uc.getOutputStream());
InputStream sml = smlStream(this.pathid);
StringBuilder xml = new StringBuilder( new Scanner(sml).useDelimiter("\\A").next());
body.print(xml);
body.close();
uc.disconnect(); // appears to make no difference
```

uc.getResponseCode() now has the value of 400

If I use curl on the same URL and same xml file in the body (curl -v -u uname:pw -T file.xml http://domain.com:8080/exist/rest/db/collection/doc.xml) sending the request under the *same* userid from the *same* machine, the document goes through and returns a 201 response as expected.  The Java version, on the other hand (using openjdk7) does nothing.

Do I have these set calls in the right order? is there some way to get more information about why the request syntax is invalid?

Comment: Turns out this may be a bit of a misleading issue: if I comment out the block that sets up the Basic Authentication, the code works (or at least it posts to the server, although it gets 401 errors instead, but at least it *does* something.

So my question is modified: *what is wrong with my Basic Auth code?*

Answer (score 0):

seems that last clue lead to a solution although not to an explanation: I replaced the call to the apache Base64 encoder with the equivalent call to sun.misc.BASE64Encoder and the code magically works as expected

```
BASE64Encoder codex = new BASE64Encoder();
String auth = codex.encode( s.getLogin().getBytes() );
uc.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + auth );
```

and all is well. org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64 is apparently broken.